# При hover показать соседний блок

Tags: html, css, css3

Здравствуйте, есть такие блоки:

```
 <div class="cl1"></div>
 ...
 <div class="cl4"></div> // у этого display:none
```

пытаюсь при ховере на класс cl1 показать блок cl4, пробовал по разному, 0 результатов

```
.cl1:hover .cl4{display:block;}
.cl1:hover +.cl4{display:block;}
.cl1:hover <.cl4{display:block;}
```

Вообщем возможно ли реализоват такое в css или только JS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Посмотреть пример**](http://jsfiddle.net/hKS79/)

```
.cl1:hover ~ .cl4{display:block;}
```

Селектор (+) выбирает элемент, идущий сразу за основным.

Comment: круто! Спасибо!

Answer (score -1):

http://jsfiddle.net/Lw6kx/3/

Полный пример с твоим случаем.

```js
$('.cl1').hover(function () {
    $(this).next('.cl4').toggle();
});
```

```css
.cl4 {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cl1">LiveD</div>
<div class="cl4">bemulima</div>
```

Comment: При такой верстке уже не работает.  

    <div class="cl1">LiveD</div>
    <div class="cl3">Test</div>
    <div class="cl4">bemulima</div>

Правильнее будет так:  

    $('.cl1').hover(function() {
        $(this).nextAll('.cl4').toggle();
    });

Comment: Это да, я тупанул, не было сделать по-другому, а то я след. элемент выбрал.